# Generating TXID from transaction's data

Tags: address, sha256, transaction-id

As I understand, we can generate a TXID by hashing transaction data through SHA256 twice, and as you know probably, A bitcoin transaction is just a bunch of data that describes the movement of bitcoins.

after that, to search a TXID in the blockchain, we should search for it in reverse byte order.

I tried this instruction to generate a TXID for some sample tx messages, but i didn't find it in blockchain explorers.

Comment: The most common mistake many people do is hashing the serialized transaction as an encoded text rather than using the bytes that the hexadecimal represents.

Comment: @Ugam I open my pcap file with wireshark and copy tx message structure as hex stream. and then hash it twice.

Comment: follow the process that is mentioned in the question I have linked.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you share the steps you took and the data you are hashing so it can be reproduced.

Comment: @Ugam

Finally I completed my C++ program to calculate TXID with double hashing of TX data and after that reverse it.

but sometimes generated TXID is not in some bitcoin explorers like https://www.blockchain.com.

why some TXID's are found and some others not found?

Comment: @Saeed As @Jbaczuk said, it would be easier for us to help you if you post the data related to the transaction and the steps that you took to get the `txid`. Otherwise we are shooting in the dark as we do not know which data matched and which did not.

Comment: @Uragm. you are right.
this is my tx raw hex data:
`01000000000102baec426dc550de28b4380ffa66d3f19bdce6ed6bc51a708145dbccadd6bd38400100000000ffffffff8cbc8d7ad78f1675ad3806`

I do double sha256 on this raw data and the output was :
`e38cc8977dba1999cf03640a997dacd1e9e6bcae255522b38d5ea43296e2fbbd`

after reverse it, final TxID is :
`bdfbe29632a45e8db3225525aebce6e9d1ac7d990a6403cf9919ba7d97c88ce3`

but it is not found!

Comment: @Saeed First of all your raw hex data is not a valid transaction. Secondly, your dsha256 is also incorrect related to that data you posted. The dsha256 of the incorrect data you posted should be `'af40edfde85a4a53256ed85df9f9b19a3c5181167431e0442421b5e6c5032b89'`

Comment: @Ugam I just coppied tx message structure hex stream data from wireshark. and I created that trasnaction myself. so the hex deta should be true, also I double hash it with sha256 online in this site:
[sha256online](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/tools/sha256/)

so it is a true way, especially that with this way I generate a lot of TXID for other transactions which all were true and found in blockchain.

Comment: @Saeed for the incorrect transaction that you have mentioned, the website hashes to the data I have mentioned. You need to check the binary option next to the box to tell the program that you are hashing hexadecimals. Now, coming back to your transaction, I don't mind how you are capturing it, but it is not a valid Bitcoin transaction.

Comment: @Ugam, Thank you. I got it. you are right. it's ok now.